# Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies, hdfs not a valid file scheme

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink

Dear swarm intelligence,

I am new to flink and hadoop, so I tried to play around with it a little bit. I have 3 Google Cloud Platform VMs on which I want to install flink and the hadoop distributed file system HDFS.
So to install HDFS, I followed a tutorial and everything seems to work. I can put, access and list files via CLI using `hdfs dfs -COMMAND /`.
So now I downloaded the binary for flink from the apache-website.
If I run e.g. the WebCount-example locally, everything works. Also, if I want to distribute the Job via `./bin/flink run -m localhost:8081 JAR` it works as well.
Only if I want to provide input and output parameter to be from HDFS, it yells the errors:

```java
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies.
```

and

```java
Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 'hdfs'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.
```

Command:

```
./bin/flink run -m localhost:8081 examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/test/hello.txt
```

I already tried copying the flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-10.0.jar and flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.12-1.12.1.jar into the lib folder as some helpers suggested on stackoverflow.
But it didn't work.

Hadoop version: 3.3.0

Flink Version: 1.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem for in an uni assignment ;)
My solution:

- download https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html
- add to vm
- set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to output of hadoop classpath command

Comment: What does `add to vm` mean?